# Is there such a thing as a Schottky zener?

Tags: diodes, zener, schottky

I was thinking about this when I was looking for over- and undershoot protection. If you use a zener you can clip the overshoot at a defined level (ignoring the slowness of the zener), but the undershoot will leave something like 0.7V. A Schottky diode would half this to 350mV. So, is there a Schottky zener which takes care of that, or do I have to place a common zener and a Schottky diode in parallel?

Answer (score 8):

A Schottky Zener does not exist*.
Back to back Zener and Schottky diode as you suggest, is a suitable method of minimising undershoot.

A Zener is both slow and "soft". Under high energy conditions where a substantial current will flow the zener voltage may substantially exceed its rated value. If required, faster clamping may be achieved by eg using a diode to a supply rail at the desire clamp voltage. This is the direct equivalent of the reversed Schottky to ground in your example.

A reverse biased Schottky diode is sometimes mounted across a MOSFET's gate-source pins in power driver applications, with minimum lead lengths between MOSFET and diode. The reason for this is not always obvious from inspection. 
Miller capacitance effects can couple load transients into a MOSFET's gate and promote oscilliatory "ringing" which can lead to rapid switching and device destruction. The reverse Schottky clips negative oscillation peaks to a level far below the threshold voltage of almost all FETs and prevents oscillation.

I invariably use a low wattage gate clamp zener on MOSFET gates in power applications. I seldom use a reverse Schottky. In a commercial product  with a typical MOSFET survival time of a few minutes without a zener (due to Miller coupling from an inductive load), a zener provided complete long term reliability.

---

Note that when clamping to a power supply 'rail' you need to be sure that the delivered energy does not "pump the rail voltage up" by more than is acceptable. This is seldom going to happen as the energy per clamping event x events per second = clamping power will usually be lower than the load on a typical rail.

The same applies to clamping diodes used to limit the range of voltage swing on an input line so that it is (almost) within supply rails by using diode from input to positive rail and ground. If the input energy that can flow exceeds the energy being taken from the rail the rail voltage may rise. This actually happens in some real world cases. I have seen an  application note published by a major microcontroller manufacturer that used input diodes for "protection" of an input (test probe) to which AC mains could be applied. In such a case the energy flow would have been in excess of the 5V rail load and the supply would have risen to unknown higher voltage.

---

- Note: * "Does not exist" is a strong claim. The two technologies are fundamentally different. I've never seen one but a hybrid design could be built and may exist, but simply using two components is so easy that there would not be vast demand for what would be a relatively specialised part.

Comment: I agree that they're different technologies, but I was thinking a Schottky diode will also have an avalanche effect?

Comment: No, a Schottky diode does not have an avalanche or breakdown effect of any sort. If you exceed their rated value with any sort of energy available they will be destroyed. Your original idea was fine. Note that if you use a reverse Schottky like this it must have a reverse polarity voltage rating at least as high as the maximum voltage that will occur across the zener. As noted above, for very short periods this can be substantially more than the zener's rated voltage.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Could you please point me to some references about the line "*A reverse biased Schottky diode is sometimes mounted across a MOSFET's gate-source pins in power driver applications*"? I have an inexplicable occasional and random MOSFET destruction occurring on a pair of MOSFETS driving a capacitive load. I am hoping that Schottky might resolve it, but I'm looking for context behind that failure mode. Thanks.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I can't provide immediate references without searching and I've got to rush at present BUT you'll find the practice is well established and recommended by some large manufacturers. As I note in the anser above the aim is to suppress parasitic oscillations by clamping one half cycle at a voltage level below Vgsth for most devices.   | Also sometimes used is to slide a ferrite bead onto the device lead so it sits against the package before soldering - on eg a TO220 device this does not interfere with mounting. | I almost always use the gate zener clamp mentioned above. ...

Comment: ... If there is any chance of reactive coupling of energy to the gate or of Miller capacitance coupling from the drain circuit then this usually makes a vast difference. Literally an application with time to FET fatality of a few minutes (heavily inductive load random PWMd :-) ) can be rendered long term reliable.

Comment: Thanks @RussellMcMahon. My case is random fatality of FET, almost certainly at powerdown or when unpowered. No rush, but would appreciate typical failure case references, and whether Schottky diodes are known beneficial for both GS and GD, or only one of those.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I don't know if I mentined a GD zener anywhere here - I may have as a typo only in this context BUT in fact GD also has it's place - with care. If you use a say 100V GD zener then if VDS exceeds about 100V the FET will turn on and clamp the D voltage. The risk is is slew rate of D signal is high it may carry VGS past it's limit before FET clamps VDS. Placing another zener GS combats this but I'm still nervous about Vdg zeners., | In you case if I had not tried a GS zener and reverse gs Schottky I'd do so as the cost and effort is low and it may well work.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Fatality at power down may be due to inductive energy dump as cct is depowered - I'd need to see the circuit. Or perhaps the FET is turned partially on as gate drive circuits lose voltage so that you get a conductive resistive state and high dissipation. Fatality when unpowered is trickier. How do you now it dies when unpowered - do you test for death WHILE unpowered or is it dead on powering on - which may be caused BY powering on.  Unpowered death might be caused by electrostatic charge buildup on an unpowered unprotected gate (usually ccts will allow for this) or ...

Comment: @AnindoGhosh ... or perhaps electrostatic or other buildup of voltage on Drain when cct is unpowed. Slow buildup could produce voltages > usual HV until FET breaks down. || I'd expect death while active or during on/off or off/on transitions as more likely. | Are gate ccts protected against over voltage? Are there GS Zeners?   Is there large inductive kick at power down? Does cct go into linear dissipation at shut down? ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want Schottky-based zener, you may use just regular Schottky diode going to separate VCC-0.2V rail from separate linear regulator. This would give you precise overshoot control for some 0.5$ extra cost, and would allow high currents, contrary to zener diodes.

Comment: Yes. Maybe Vcc-0.3. If precision of voltage matters (and it seldom would to this extent) linear regulator would need an output reservoir cap large enough to rise only acceptably under one transient event and  would be loaded such that delivered energy from an "event" had all been removed prior to next event.